# Those Mouse Events Are Confusing

Tags: wpf

I am playing around with mouse events and I realized there are a bunch of events but I have no idea when to use which one.

There is the `Click` event, `MouseDown` event, `PreviewMouseDown`, `PreviewLeftButtonMouseDown`, `LeftButtonMouseDown`.

What are the differences between then? They all do the same and that is notifying once mouse being pressed.

When shall I use which for what?

Comment: MSDN documents all of these fairly well.  E.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752279.aspx to give differences with Preview events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click event : The user has clicked the element and released the button

MouseDown event: The user has pressed the mouse button (before releasing it). Click happens to be called if the user has both pressed and release it on the same element.

PreviewMouseDown : same as mousedown, except it is a tunnel event. It is called on parent function first, then tunneled to the child container while mousedown bubbles upwards (on child container first, and then on parent containers).

LeftButtonMouseDown : Called when left mouse button is pressed

PreviousLeftButtonMouseDown : I am not sure about this event. Could not find it. Did you mean PreviewLeftButtonMouseDown?